# Смешение времён (прошёдшего, настоящего и будущего) при описании прошлого

Tags: грамматика, семантика, времена

Допускается ли такое сочетание времён:

**Джон поступил в колледж. Несколько лет он усердно учится. Однако ему не удастся получить работу в банке, как он надеется. После окончания университета Джон делает карьеру в политике.**

Answer (score 0):

Джон поступил в колледж: несколько лет он усердно учится, однако ему не удастся получить работу в банке, как он надеется. После окончания университета Джон делает карьеру в политике... - последнее выглядит незавершенным по мысли, употребление континиуса "делает карьеру" больше походит на обстоятельство, чем на сказуемое, либо на придаточное предложение содержащее обстоятельство другого дела.  Двоеточие(если я правильно выбрал знак=)) купирует этот момент показывая что  измененное время относится к прошлому, когда "Джон поступил".

Либо вот так оформить:

Джон поступил в колледж: несколько лет он усердно учится, однако ему не удастся получить работу в банке, как он надеется; после окончания университета Джон делает карьеру в политике... - но, опять же, последнее предложение не закончено и еще странно, что колледж становится университетом.